# sqlserver 2005 Splitting a date range into consecutive years

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to take two dates in a record, and split them into defined years bands.  These bands/buckets are all exactly a year. I've been at it for a while now but I don't seem to be able to get a starting point in year two!

Some test data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##PolicyUWYear') IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE ##PolicyUWYear
        END 
    CREATE TABLE ##PolicyUWYear
        (
         PolicyNumber [nvarchar](50)  
        ,PolicyStartDate datetime
        ,PolicyEndDate datetime
        )
    ON  [PRIMARY]

Insert into ##PolicyUWYear Values ('RMO33032207' ,  '2014-03-04 00:00:00.000','2017-03-04 00:00:00.000'  )
    Insert into ##PolicyUWYear Values ('RMO33000999' ,  '2013-10-04 00:00:00.000','2016-10-04 00:00:00.000'  ) 
    Insert into ##PolicyUWYear Values ('AMO05000888' ,  '2014-09-04 00:00:00.000','2014-12-04 00:00:00.000'  ) 
    Insert into ##PolicyUWYear Values ('QQO05000333' ,  '2014-10-04 00:00:00.000','2015-10-04 00:00:00.000'  )
```

This creates a table that looks like this:

[image]

What I want is it splitting into defined buckets.. as below (not complete using all test data):

[image]

This is confused by a few things.. the biggest one is that each underwriting year starts on October 10th and ends of September 30th - meaning a record can start in August 2014 but still be part of the 2013 underwriting year.

For example '2013 to 2014 UnderwritingYear Start' is 2013-10-01 and 
2013 to 2014 UnderwritingYear End is 2014-09-30.

Records can be of various lengths... most are 3 or 5 years.. but some can be shorter!  Basically, it's finance, so the customers have odd and ideas...

Any help gratefully received - I started thinking it would be quite straightforward, and found that it wasn't. Having said that it might be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic here is cumbersome, but you can do it.  It requires a lot of conditional aggregation.  I think the following encapsulates the logic:

```
select PolicyNumber,
       max(case when PolicyEndDate <= '2013-09-30' then NULL
                when PolicyStartDate <= '2014-09-30'
                then dateadd(year,
                             datediff(month, PolicyStartDate, '2014-09-30') / 12,
                             PolicyStartDate
                            )
           end) as UW_start_2013,
       max(case when PolicyStartDate > '2014-09-30' then NULL
                when PolicyEndDate > '2013-09-30' and PolicyEndDate <= '2014-09-30'
                then PolicyEndDate
                when PolicyEndDate > '2014-09-30'
                then dateadd(year,
                             1 + (datediff(month, PolicyStartDate, '2014-09-30') / 12),
                             PolicyStartDate
                            )
           end) as UW_end_2013,
       max(case when PolicyEndDate <= '2013-09-30' then NULL
                when PolicyStartDate <= '2015-09-30'
                then dateadd(year,
                             datediff(month, PolicyStartDate, '2015-09-30') / 12,
                             PolicyStartDate
                            )
           end) as UW_start_2014,
       max(case when PolicyStartDate > '2015-09-30' then NULL
                when PolicyEndDate > '2014-09-30' and PolicyEndDate <= '2015-09-30'
                then PolicyEndDate
                when PolicyEndDate > '2015-09-30'
                then dateadd(year,
                             1 + (datediff(month, PolicyStartDate, '2015-09-30') / 12),
                             PolicyStartDate
                            )
           end) as UW_end_2014
from PolicyUWYear
group by PolicyNumber;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68a29/11) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Excellent. That's nearly it! The only issue I can see ( although I haven't tested it properly using my data - it's Friday!) is that the record starting AM which only has a three month timeframe doesn't quite work. It's very much a start tho! Many thanks for taking time.

Comment: hi Gordon - Thanks for your help - it really set me off on the right path.  I ended up writing a couple of functions based on your code that seem to do the job - as below: